# Subtracting 2 points on a plane gives a point that lines on another plane parallel to original plane?

Tags: vector-spaces, plane-geometry

Consider 2 points $x_1$ and $x_2$ on some plane $wx+b = 0$.

If we draw the vector from the origin to each point, the vector is represented by $x_1$ and $x_2$. Isn't this vector on the plane $wx+b=0$? This is my intuition when I draw the vectors.

However, if I subtract $wx_2+b=0$ from $wx_1 + b =0$, I get
$$
w(x_1 - x_2) = 0
$$

This plane no longer has the offset term, so it is indeed parallel to $wx+b=0$. But this seems to contradict what I said earlier about how $x_1 - x_2$ being a vector on the original plane?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this has to do with the distinction between a point and a vector. If the vector $\vec{x_1}$ points from the origin to a point on the plane and the vector $\vec{x_2}$ points from the origin to another point on the plane. This means the vector $\vec{x_1} - \vec{x_2}$ lies in the plane since it is the vector connecting the two points.

If a vector $\vec{x}$ is a position vector that emanates out of the origin, then the point that $\vec{x}$ points to lies on the plane if it satisfies the equation $\vec{w} \cdot \vec{x} + b = 0$. Thus, $\vec{w} \cdot \vec{x_1} + b = 0$ and $\vec{w} \cdot \vec{x_2} + b = 0$ for position vectors $\vec{x_1}$ and $\vec{x_2}$ pointing to points on the plane.

Which means $\vec{w} \cdot (\vec{x_1} - \vec{x_2}) = 0$.

All this says is that the vector $\vec{x_1} - \vec{x_2}$ is perpendicular to the vector $\vec{w}$ which is the normal vector to the plane. You assumed that $\vec{x_1}$ and $\vec{x_2}$ point to points on the plane. $\vec{x_1} - \vec{x_2}$ being perpendicular to the normal vector $\vec{w}$ does not contradict this.

Actually, $\vec{x_1}$ and $\vec{x_2}$ are position vectors from the origin to points on the plane. So they satisfy a different equation than $\vec{x_1} - \vec{x_2}$, which lies in the plane, does. This doesn't mean $\vec{x_1} - \vec{x_2}$ is not in the same plane that $\vec{x_1}$ and $\vec{x_2}$ point to, just that it satisfies a different equation to lie in the same plane than $\vec{x_1}$ and $\vec{x_2}$ do.

Comment: Right, I agree with that. But what is the notion of "subtracting 2 points on a plane gives a point on another plane parallel to the original plane?" I don't quite understand this.

Comment: @David By subtracting 2 points on a plane do you mean subtracting the vectors that point to those points? Because you can't subtract points. In that case, the difference in the points would be on the same plane (if by points you mean the vector pointing to the points).

Comment: Yes to the first question. In my work above, it seems to suggest that the resulting point $x_1 - x_2$ is on another plane because essentially, I picked 2 arbitrary points on the plane $wx + b = 0$. Then say the 3rd point, let's call it $x_3$, is defined by the vector pointing to this point, which is $x_1-x_2$. Then we see $wx_3 = 0$. Because $x_1, x_2$ were arbitrary, $x_3$ here is also arbitrary, and it appears to lie on the plane $wx = 0$, which is a plane parallel to $wx + b = 0$?

Comment: @David My edited answer might help

Comment: @David Another source of confusion is that I think the vector $w$ is assumed to start on the surface of the plane and be normal to it. The equation $w \cdot (x_1-x_2) = 0$ seems to imply $x_1-x_2$ is in a different plane but remember $x_1-x_2$ is not a vector emanating out of the origin (it is a vector in the plane) so its dot product with $w$ being 0 implies a very different thing (i.e. that it's perpendicular to the vector $w$ which is normal to the plane) than if it was emanating out of the origin where it would mean that it lies in the plane $w \cdot x = 0$.

Comment: Ah this last comment cleared things up I think. I can't remember where I heard it, but I do recall someone stating "subtracting 2 points on a plane gives a point on a plane parallel to original plane." Now I can't remember where I heard it, but it seems to not make sense.